# How do I adjust segments and rings on a UV Sphere?

Tags: mesh, interface

I'm working with a UV Sphere and I need to adjust its segments and rings. When I first added it to the scene a menu called, "Add UV Sphere" appeared. Unfortunately, the menu then went away. How do I call it up again?

I found relevant video suggesting that pressing F6 will call up the menu again, but F6 does nothing on my system (I tried to find out what F6 is supposed to do, but searching for F6 in Preferences > Keymap > Key-Binding yields no results; in fact the search field doesn't appear to recognize function keys at all). Any suggestions? Thanks.

[image: Add UV Sphere menu]

Comment: it should be F9, not F6, but as soon as you do anything else (like move, edit...) you won't be able to have access to the last action

Comment: Thank you moonboots. Looks like once I've created a mesh, any further subdividing is done this way: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html

Comment: yes once you've created a primitive you can't change the initial settings anymore as soon as you move or edit etc... but of course you can still do whatever you want like subdivide etc